# Many to One or Many to Many mapping in ROLE-PERMISSION Scenario

Tags: hibernate, orm, many-to-many, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I am new to Hibernate and just going through few samples

After going through few samples, I am still confused on deciding the relation between tables.

consider the scenarion, I have Role and Permission assigned to it like

```
Role              Permission
------------------------------------------------------
ROLE_ADMIN    =   Create, Update, Delete, View
ROLE_MANAGER  =   Update, View
ROLE_VIEWER   =   View
```

In this scenario, I have created my tables like this,

```
Role
-----
role_id(PK) role_name

Permission  
-----------
permission_id(PK) permission_name

Role_Permission
-----------------
role_permission_id   role_id(FK)    permission_id(FK)
```

Now, In this case 1 Role can have many Permisssion and Many Permission can belong to One Role, So I think it is One-to-Many relation considering this figure in my mind,

```
Role_Permission
-----------------
role_permission_id   role_id(FK)    permission_id(FK)
----------------------------------------------------------
1--------------------1---------------1     
2--------------------1---------------2     
3--------------------1---------------3     
4--------------------2---------------1     
5--------------------2---------------3
```

Role having Id 1 is mapped to many Permission having Id as 1, 2, 3.
and Many Permission like 1, 2, 3 belongs to One Role having id as 1

So I think it is One-To-Many

---

I also think it falls under Many-To-Many as well,
Considering this picture in my mind,

```
role_permission_id   role_id(FK)    permission_id(FK)
----------------------------------------------------------
1--------------------1---------------1     
2--------------------1---------------2     
3--------------------1---------------3     
4--------------------2---------------1     
5--------------------2---------------3
```

Role having Id 1, 2 is mapped to many Permission having Id as 1, 2, 3.
and Many Permission like 1, 2, 3 belongs to many Role having id as 1 and 2

So I think it is Many-To-Many

---

I also think it falls under Many-to-One,

```
role_permission_id   role_id(FK)    permission_id(FK)
----------------------------------------------------------
1--------------------1---------------1     
2--------------------1---------------2     
3--------------------1---------------3     
4--------------------2---------------1     
5--------------------2---------------3
```

Role having Id 1, 2 is mapped to Permission having Id as 1.
Permission having id as 1 belongs to many Role having id as 1 and 2

So I think it is Many-To-One

I am really confused on how to judge the Mappings, can Someone please clear my doubt.
Also, I would like to know the Thumb Rule on what basis Mappings need to be decided.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Seems in your case its better to choose Many - to -Many raltionship. so You will have Permission, Role tables and junk table Permission_Role table. 
try this tutorial: 


  [1]: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/ 

Are you creating it from database? I can suggest easy ways for mapping...
```